# Android splash activity displays behind system bars

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen

I am using a theme to make a splash screen from a drawable. However, the drawable for the splash screen displays behind system bars, as seen below.

[image: Splash screen window background displays behind system bars]

Here is my splash screen drawable `splash_screen.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/slighty_red" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/test_icon"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Here is my theme for the splash screen:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>   <!--Tried this but it doesn't work-->
</style>
```

And then I applied this theme to my splash activity in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have already tried setting fitsSystemWindows to true in the splash theme, and my splash activity has no layout file to set fitsSystemWindows to true in.

How can I make it so my splash screen doesn't display behind the system bars?

Comment: rather than make it displaying it that way, why make it full screen instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution:

In the splash theme, change

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
```

now the splash screen drawable will not draw behind the system bars

source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119638/splash-screen-using-android-windowbackground-does-goes-behind-statusbar

Answer (score 1):

A simple and quick fix with `android:paddingTop="20dp"` if you don't want to spend more time in debugging this issue

Answer (score 1):

This will make your Splash Screen go full screen mode. Just add this on your `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`.

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `onCreate()` before `setContentView()`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This will make your `splash screen fullscreen`

Comment: No, it will not. you will get this error `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

Comment: I have done this by making the `setContentView()` first then the code for making the page full screen and I don't encounter an error

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Splash theme :

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove status bar then use this before `setContentView(layout)` in `onCreateView` method

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Or Set `paddingTop ="20dp"` on parent layout in your XML design.

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> <!--use this to make the activity full screen-->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your oncreate,

```
   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            /** Hiding Title bar of this activity screen */
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            /** Making this activity, full screen */
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            //setLayout
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}
```

and set your theme to Theme.AppCompact.NoActionBar